# Android and how to handle userdatabases

Tags: java, android, mysql, server

I have developed a few apps in my days, but only small local applications.
I want to start working on more advanced apps, and I have a few ideas that require me to keep track of usernames, scores etc, Online.

Lets say im looking for a way to keep track of usernames/passwords, making sure the usernames are unique, and updating the client sqlite database aswell as server database whenever they go online.

So far the only ways I can think of is creating a java servlet or posting and recieving data through PHP and into a MYSQL database. (which I have done some testing on... and I dont really like it).

What is the common/best way to do this? Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you need is a web service hosted somewhere to perform the tasks you need, such as ensuring unique usernames etc.

I would suggest creating a REST service for this, perhaps look into JAX-RS for this, but any REST framework would suit you.

On the Android front, you would need a (de)serializer, such as [Google's GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)   which will enable you to convert Java objects to/from JSON seamlessly.

Finally, something like [Square's RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) will make it much easier to call on that external REST api from your Android code.

These are just a few of the possibilities - there are alternatives to all of these libraries if you don't like any of them.

Comment: appreciate the input! Will look into all of this.